# removing brackets from list inside pandas cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe :

```
Team    Age
 X       [28,21,16,45]
 B       [18,19,16,23]
 Y       [32,27,34,23]
```

And all I want is to get the brackets off the Age column to go further. I am doing the following:

```
 df['Age']=[','.join(i) for i in df['Age']]
```

But  I get the **can only join an iterable** error when doing so; If i go through a loop and print the result I able to get what want.

Comment: What is `print (type(df['Age'].iat[0]))` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If values are strings:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].str.strip('[]')
```

If values are lists:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].str.join(',')
```

Comment: great. Much easier than I thought. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(str).str[1:-1]
```

If the `'Age'` column is a string column, just use:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].str[1:-1]
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is the desired output.